# MonoDevelop command line compile a solution

Tags: mono, monodevelop, xbuild

The problem is as follows: I have a MonoDevelop project (ASP.NET) on my development workstation.

I'm currently at a customer site, without my regular development environment on my laptop (Regulatory Burden). I have SSH access to my development workstation, but the network is too laggy to handle X11 comfortably.

I need to make a minor adjustment and recompile. I tried using xbuild, with no effect:

```
qdot@trigati ~/svn/proj/trunk/proj $ xbuild proj.csproj
XBuild Engine Version 2.6.4.0
Mono, Version 2.6.4.0
Copyright (C) Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2009.
MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0000: /home/qdot/svn/proj/trunk/proj/proj.csproj: Imported project: 
"/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v8.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" does not exist.
```

Is there some utility that can trigger a rebuild of the monodevelop sourcecode? Obviously the code builds through the GUI.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
mdtool build proj.csproj
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  As a result of your post, I added the following to a .bashrc file:  alias mdb="mdtool build $(find . -name '*.csproj')"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use xbuild, create a symlink:

cd /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v9.0

ln -s v9.0 v10.0

I have the same exact ubuntu 12.04 distro on two different computers and could not figure out why mono would compile on one computer and not the other. But oh well, symlink solved the problem.