# Can the msbuild nantcontrib task be used with mono's xbuild?

Tags: mono, continuous-integration, nant, nantcontrib, xbuild

I'm curious if it's possible to use the nantcontrib  task in combination with Mono's xbuild.exe instead of it's intended msbuild.exe.

My initial experiments aren't looking too promising; the  task looks for msbuild.exe, so I symlink'd xbuild.exe to msbuild.exe but the task is failing with a

```
External Program Failed: /usr/lib/mono/2.0/msbuild.exe (return code was 1):
```

Is it possible to use xbuild as a direct substitute for msbuild?  If not, any input on getting a NAnt task to build a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) under mono would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that this question is a bit unspecific. You might have more luck with this by directly asking in the Nant support forums.

Comment: I'll try, but it's hard to say if whether it's a NAnt/NAntContrib/Mono question--so I figured I'd ask the collective developer brain of the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401257/monodevelop-command-line-compile-a-solution). Furthermore, consider using NAnt's simple `<exec>` element instead of NAntContrib's `<msbuild>` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Babak; I've settled that the answer to my question is "no, the <msbuild> task isn't compatible with xbuild".  Thanks for the tip about the <exec> task--it's working very well :D